# goldenlayout js library integration with angular examples

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to find some examples for the goldenlayout js library integration with angular, other than the examples available on their website. I would like to use something like contentURL's to point to other html, not using templates.

Thx

Comment: Why you've added tag dll?